# C# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, nullreferenceexception, visual-web-developer-2010

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Whenever I run my program, I get a NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.

So when I start the program I have a form appear where I am supposed to choose from a list of names and be able to update the details or delete them, but nothing appears in the drop down list.

I get the null reference at:

```
comm.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value =
employeesList.SelectedItem.Value;
```

This is the select button in the CS file:

```
protected void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare objects
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    // Read the connection string from Web.config
    string connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "HelpDesk"].ConnectionString;
    // Initialize connection
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    // Create command
    comm = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Username, Address, City, County, Post Code, " +
        "HomePhone, Extension, MobilePhone FROM Employees " +
        "WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID", conn);
    // Add command parameters
    comm.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value =
        employeesList.SelectedItem.Value;
    // Enclose database code in Try-Catch-Finally
    try
    {
        // Open the connection
        conn.Open();
        // Execute the command
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        // Display the data on the form
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            firstnameTextBox.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            lastnameTextBox.Text = reader["lastName"].ToString();
            userNameTextBox.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
            addressTextBox.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
            cityTextBox.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
            countyTextBox.Text = reader["county"].ToString();
            postcodeTextBox.Text = reader["Post Code"].ToString();
            homePhoneTextBox.Text = reader["HomePhone"].ToString();
            extensionTextBox.Text = reader["Extension"].ToString();
            mobilePhoneTextBox.Text = reader["MobilePhone"].ToString();
        }
        // Close the reader 
        reader.Close();
        // Enable the Update button
        updateButton.Enabled = true;
        // Enable the Delete button
        deleteButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Display error message
        dbErrorLabel.Text =
            "Error loading the employee details!<br />";
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the connection
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

And this the code in the aspx file:

```
<p>
<asp:Label ID="dbErrorLabel" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
Select an employee to update:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="employeesList" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="selectButton" Text="Select" runat="server"
    onclick="selectButton_Click" />
```

Comment: NullReference are easiest to fix. Enable break when any exception is thrown from VS. Go to Debug-->Exception. check the Thrown for CLR Exception

Comment: Has an item from `employeesList` been selected?

Comment: Why aren't you wrapping your code in a try/catch block?  Also, why are you adding the parameter before setting its value?

Comment: @keyboardP. When I run the program there is noting to select. it's blank.

Comment: @user331742 - In that case it would be null which is why you're getting that error. Check MisterXero's answer to see how to check if something is null.

Comment: @user331742 - "What do you mean by try/catch block? " - It's an exception handler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Brian. I'm new to this. I thought I had done this???

Comment: Debugger is your friend. I ALWAYS wonder on these types of questions  when debugger can tell you what's wrong immediately. Please learn how to use it. You will save you some time.

Comment: @TomasVoracek - Debugger isn't telling me anything, it's appearing blank

Answer (score 6):

Put a breakpoint at:

```
comm.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value =
        employeesList.SelectedItem.Value;
```

When you run you program check the value of:

```
employeesList.SelectedItem
```

Most likely this will be null if no item has been selected. Try checking for a null value before using:

```
 if (employeesList.SelectedItem != null)
 {
comm.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value =
    employeesList.SelectedItem.Value;
 }
 else
 {
// Handle this case
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It may very well be that `employeesList` is the objec that is null. Attempting to access a property of a null object will throw this error. So your check `employeesList.SelectedItem` may also cause a Null Reference Exception

Comment: @EtherDragon `employeesList` is a control, so it won't be null.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev But SelectedItem IS null obviously...

Comment: @TomasVoracek I wasn't talking about SelectedItem. I was referring to "It may very well be that `employeesList` is the objec that is null". The control itself will not be null.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you added any items to your dropdown list.

You have:

```
<p>
<asp:Label ID="dbErrorLabel" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
Select an employee to update:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="employeesList" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="selectButton" Text="Select" runat="server"
    onclick="selectButton_Click" />
```

But a dropdown list should have items like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="employeesList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1" Selected="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You may want to add that if the user does not select any items then the SelectedItem may still be null so he should check for null before using it.

Comment: Ideally, the first item should be something like "Select one" or another default value, and then have that with Selected="true". Then check for that value before proceeding.

Comment: I have a table in my database that it is supposed to get the data from and display it in the drop down list

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fill your data in the drop down list from the table available in the database.

Sample Code:
In Page_Load,

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   ddlName.DataSource=ds;
   ddlName.DataValueField="ID";
   ddlName.DataTextField="NAME";
   ddlName.DataBind();
}
```